# magento stop checkout

Tags: magento, checkout

I need to stop the checkout if a special Attribute of a Product has value one and the shipping address is international. In addition if the weight is over 31.5 and shipping address is international the checkout should be stopped.

Does anyone know how to start?

Comment: Webshopapps are a good place to go for shipping extensions with this type of depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

improve your shipping method validation to achieve this

Comment: ok thx. But when i coded the logic of that how can i stop the checkout in the shippingmethod. So that the continue button are not displayed and the order cannot be placed?

Comment: if you make your shipping method not available then you just can't checkout without shipping method selection